# Powershell Adding Spaces

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to combine strings in powershell to generate a file path.  I am learning the basics and have put together this syntax

```
$fileDirectory = "C:\Pics\"

foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem $fileDirectory){
    #Setting parent dir to check
    $ParentDir = "E:\Main Folder\"

    #setting param to split
    $parts =$file.Name -split '\.'

    #capturing variables
    $PictureYear = $parts[0].Trim()
    $PictureMonth = $parts[1].substring(0,3)

    #Writing To window to confirm variables are accurate
    Write-Host $PictureYear
    Write-Host $PictureMonth

    #checking if folders exist
    Write-Host $($ParentDir)$($PictureYear)\
}
```

But when I `Write-Host` there is a space in the filepath.  The output is

```
E:\Main Folder\ 2016 \
```

How can I remove the space?  I tried using the `Trim()` operator but the space still exists.

Comment: Look into Join-Path and Split-Path.

Comment: @KoryGill - thank you for pointing in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to burst your bubble, but there's already a cmdlet and a .Net method to combine paths:

```
Join-Path -Path $ParentDir -ChildPath $PictureYear
$ParentDir | Join-Path -ChildPath $PictureYear | Join-Path -ChildPath $PictureMonth

[System.IO.Path]::Combine($ParentDir, $PictureYear, $PictureMonth)

$parts = @($ParentDir) + $parts  # array of all components    
[System.IO.Path]::Combine([string[]]$parts)
```

Comment: Not bursting bubble at all!  This is excellent and a wonderful example.